# Vertex coloring inherited from perfect matchings (motivated by quantum physics)

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, graph-colorings, perfect-matchings

**Added (19.01.2021):** [Dustin Mixon wrote a blog post](https://dustingmixon.wordpress.com/2021/01/18/a-graph-coloring-problem-from-quantum-physics-with-prizes/) about the question where he reformulated and generalized the question.

**Added (25.12.2020):** I made a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/07b1lIWX94k) to explain the question in detail.

**Added (24.08.2019):** As I consider this question important for quantum physics, I have announced a 3000 Euro award on its solution, see [here for more details](https://mariokrenn.wordpress.com/graph-theory-question/).

---

The following purely graph-theoretic question is motivated by quantum mechanics (and a special case of the questions asked [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.06023)).

**Bi-Colored Graph**: A bi-colored weighted graph $G=(V(G),E(G))$, on $n$ vertices with $d$ colors is an undirected, not necessarily simple graph where there is a fixed ordering of the vertices $V(G)=v_1, \ldots, v_n$ and to each edge $e \in E(G)$ there is a complex weight $w_e$  and an ordered pair of (not necessarily different) colors $(c_1(e),c_2(e))$ associated with it from the $d$ possible colors. We say that an edge is monochromatic if the associated pair of colors are not different, otherwise the edge is bi-chromatic. Moreover, if $e$ is an edge incident to the vertices $v_i,v_j \in V(G)$ with $i<j$ and the associated ordered pair of colors to $e$ is $(c_1(e),c_2(e))$ then we say that $e$ is colored $c_1$ at  $v_i$  and $c_2$ at $v_j$.

We will be interested in a special coloring of this graph:

**Inherited Vertex Coloring:** Let $G$ be a bi-colored weighted graph and $PM$ denote a perfect matching in $G$. We associate a coloring of the vertices of G with PM in the natural way: for every vertex $v_i$ there is a single edge $e(v_i) \in PM$ that is incident to $v_i$, let the color of $v_i$ be the color of $e(v_i)$ at $v_i$. We call this coloring $c$, the inherited vertex coloring (IVC) of the perfect matching PM.

**Weight of Vertex Coloring**: Let $G$ be a bi-colored weighted graph. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of perfect matchings of $G$ which have the coloring $c$ as their inherited vertex coloring. We define the weight of $c$ as
$$w(c) := \sum_{PM \in \mathcal{M}} \prod_{e \in PM}w_e. $$
Moreover, if $w(c)$=1 we say that the coloring gets unit weight, and if $w(c)$=0 we say that the coloring cancels out.

> **Question**: For which values of $n$ and $d$ are there bi-colored graphs on $n$ vertices and $d$ different colors with the property that all the $d$ monochromatic colorings have unit weight, and every other coloring cancels out?

We call such graphs monochromatic with respect to the IVC.

- The only known examples are $C_{2n}$ and $K_4$. Furthermore, [Ilya Bogdanov](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267002/graphs-with-only-disjoint-perfect-matchings) has shown that,  if all $w_e$ are positive real numbers, these examples are the only solutions.

---

**Example of Inherited Vertex Coloring:**
[image]
A bi-chromatic weighted edge with one double edge between vertex 4 and 6 is shown on the top left, the edge weights $E_{ij}$ are shown below. On the right top, its eight perfect matchings are shown, and $w(PM_i)$ denotes the product of the edge weights of the perfect matching $PM_i$. The perfect matching 4 and 5 have the same inherited vertex coloring. As $w(c)=w(PM_4)+w(PM_5)=0$, we say this coloring cancels out. There are six remaining IVCs with nonzero weights, three of them are monochromatic, while three others are non-monochromatic. Therefore, the graph is not monochromatic.

---

PS: This problem can be [rephrased entirely in terms of equation systems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/341983/equation-system-with-exponentially-many-equations-in-quadratic-many-variables), without the connections to graph theory, as [Alex Ravsky](https://mathoverflow.net/users/43954/alex-ravsky) has already suggested.

Comment: Do we allow multiple edges (of different colors/bicolors) connecting the same pair of vertices?

Comment: yes, multiedges are allowed (i specify that now).

Comment: Are multicolor edges necessary? It seems that appropriate weights are enough to fulfill property 2.

Comment: @Bullet51 The multi-color of edges are additional degree-of-freedom, but does not need to be used. Same with the ability to use multi-edges.

Comment: Am I right thet a bichromatic edge is _directed_, i.e., that it is specified which its endpoint should get which color? Can some edge heve zero weight?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov Yes, it is specified which of the endpoints get which color (i clarify that now, thanks), and the weights are arbitrary numbers in $\mathbb{C}$ including zero. (However, I think edges with weights zero cannot help, because all PMs where it is contained has PM-weight zero [as the PM weight is constructed multiplicative of its edge-weights]).

Comment: As for me, the question doesn’t look hopeless, so I sent an inspiring letter to five strong related specialists and I hope we’ll make a group to attack it.