# Has this notion of vertex-coloring of graphs been studied?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

In a study of a quantum physics problem, I came about an apparently very natural type of vertex colorings of a graph. The colors of the vertex $v_i$ is inherited from perfect matchings $PM$ of an edge-colored graph:

> **Definition:** (*inherited vertex coloring $c$ of $PM$*) Let $G(V,E)$ be a graph who's edges $e \in E$ are colored. For every vertex $v_i$ in an edge-colored graph $G$, there is a single edge $e(v_i) \in PM$ that is incident to $v_i$, let the color of $v_i$ be the color of $e(v_i)$.

A graph with $n$ perfect matchings has $n$ (not necessarily different) inherited vertex colorings $c$; let's call the set of all inherited vertex colors $\mathcal{C}$. One could now ask about properties of $\mathcal{C}$. For example, [Ilya Bogdanov](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267002/graphs-with-only-disjoint-perfect-matchings) has shown that if all $c \in \mathcal{C}$ are monochromatic, then $|\mathcal{C}|\leq3$, and if $|\mathcal{C}|=3$, then $|c|=4$.

It seems to me that this notion of vertex coloring is so natural, that it makes me wonder the following:

> **Question**: Has this (or similar) notions of vertex colorings been studied before? Isit be known under other names, maybe not under the name *coloring* but *labeling*? Is it related to other properties studied in graph theory?

---

**An example:**

[image]
A graph with 6 vertices. The three perfect matchings lead to three inherited vertex colorings.

---

One can asked [other](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311325/vertex-coloring-inherited-from-perfect-matchings-motivated-by-quantum-physics), [more general questions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.06023) about it (with weighted, bi-colored graphs), but here this the most natural and simple form of coloring i believe.

---

**Added (24.08.2019)**: As I consider this property important for quantum physics, I have announced [an award for the best paper on this within the next two years, and another award for the solution of a certain question](https://mariokrenn.wordpress.com/graph-theory-question/).

Comment: Mario, the setting is not clear. Are you given a graph G PLUS a coloring of the edges (that can be arbitrary), and then for every perfect matching you color the vertices according to the color of the edges they belong to?

Comment: yes, you described it perfectly. i give G (G involves set of vertices, edges and corresponding edge colors). the vertices get the colorings in the way you describe. in general, i can start asking questions about existance of a graph G, which produce specific vertex coloring. such questions naturally follow from quantum mechanical questions about creatability of certain quantum states.